# Application based on socket connection, works well in Android 2.3 but not in android 4.2

Tags: android, sockets

I have developed an android app, which works well in android 2.3 but not in android 4.2.

The app creates a socket connection and sends data to the server. The problem is with socket connection. Please help me.

The code for socket connection is:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
int timeout=30000;
socket.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
//sockaddr is user defined.
//sockaddr address has server ip address and port
```

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace. If I had to guess, I'd say there's NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: is this your problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247231/no-authentication-challenge-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since Android Version 3.0 (API 11) it is not allowed to make network activity on the main thread of your app.

Here a Link to the Exception that (i think) is thrown by your app (look at your logcat for more information).
[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Try to do all your network activities with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

I hope this will help you.
=)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform Socket connection asynchronously, as from Android 3.0 onwards, this isn't allowed on Main thread.